# SVG elements appearing in DOM, but not visible

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to place a circle svg onto my page using javascript.

This is in my html:

```
<svg
      id="container"
      width="120"
      height="220"
      viewPort="0 0 120 120"
      version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const spot = document.createElement('circle')
spot.setAttribute('cx', 200)
spot.setAttribute('cy', 200)
spot.setAttribute('r', 20)

container.appendChild(spot)
```

I see the circle show up in the DOM, which I checked using Chrome dev tools Elements inspector. But the circle is not visible. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I realized that I need specify the "namespace" that the circle element is using. So the line with `createElement` becomes:

```
const spot = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle')
```

It worked!